# Why can't I return cookies in Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I was practicing with the document.cookie attribute and I was able to set and return cookies in my FireFox browswer. However, when I tried to return some cookies in google chrome I didn't return anything. Is there a reason for that? Here is my code in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1ge8qekr/).

**HTML**

```
<div id="ex1">
    <h2>Example 1</h2>
    <p></p>
    <h4>results:</h4>
    <button id="btn">Return Cookie</button>
    <button id="btn2">Set Cookie</button>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function cText(text) {
    return document.createTextNode(text);
}

function cElem(elem) {
    return document.createElement(elem);
}

function attach(id, text, elem) {
    var a = cText(text);
    var b = cElem(elem);
    b.appendChild(a);

    var c = document.getElementById(id).appendChild(b);
    return c;
}

document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function() {
    var a = document.cookie;
    attach('ex1', a, 'p');
}

/* In order to make key = values you have to make a  separate line for 
each name and value that you are going to put into the document.cookie*/
document.getElementById('btn2').onclick = function() {
    document.cookie = "name = Michael Hendricks; expires =" + dayt + ";";
    document.cookie = "occupation = Shitty Retail Clerk; expires =" + dayt + ";";
    document.cookie = "age = 26 years old with big ol man boobs; expires =" + dayt + ";";

    console.log('cookie has been saved');
}
```

Comment: Your jsfiddle works fine in my 50.0.2661.102 Chrome

Comment: @Gosha_Fighten  Yes, I see it works in jfiddle. But when I add it in a regular html file and ouput it in chrome I don't return any of the values.

Answer (score 0):

Domain must be null if you set cookies on localhost.

Comment: how do you make a domain null?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome won't set cookie for 'file://' protocol (as well as safari).
You can use '[Web Server for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb?hl=en)' to test your local web app.